# The last_run_at time is inconsistent with my current time

Tags: django, django-celery-beat

Summary:
Include a brief description of the problem here, and fill out the version info below.

Celery Version: 5.2.7
Celery-Beat Version:2.3.0
Django 4.0.7
Exact steps to reproduce the issue:
django settings.py

```py
DJANGO_CELERY_BEAT_TZ_AWARE = False
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
USE_TZ = False
```

celery

```py
app.conf.timezone = 'Asia/Shanghai'
app.conf.enable_utc = False
```

CrontabSchedule

'timezone': app.conf.timezone
Detailed information
I set the expires property of the task, but the task does not stop executing when it expires.
I checked the task data and found that the last_run_at is 8 hours ahead of the current time.
I think it might be a time zone issue,but both django and celery I set timezone='Asia/Shanghai' and set enable_utc=False.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem

The last_run_at time is consistent with my current time